# How to remove files from a directory if their names are not in a text file? Bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, filenames, delete-file

I am writing a bash script and want it to tell me if the names of the files in a directory appear in a text file and if not, remove them.

Something like this:

```
counter = 1
numFiles = ls -1 TestDir/ | wc -l 
while [$counter -lt $numFiles]
do
     if [file in TestDir/ not in fileNames.txt]
     then
          rm file
     fi
     ((counter++))
done
```

So what I need help with is the `if` statement, which is still pseudo-code.

Comment: Have you tried using `grep` to check if `file` is in `fileNames.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your script logic a lot :

```
#/bin/bash

# for loop to iterate over all files in the testdir
for file in TestDir/*
do
    # if grep exit code is 1 (file not found in the text document), we delete the file
    [[ ! $(grep -x "$file" fileNames.txt &> /dev/null) ]] && rm "$file"
done
```

Comment: This makes sense to me but something is not working because it is just removing all the files. Should there be quotes around fileNames.txt?

Comment: Nvm, got it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: The grep line could be even more simplified (not tested): `grep "$file" fileNames.txt &> /dev/null || rm -f "$file"`

Comment: This will delete the file `foobar12.txt` if you have a file called `fo` in the list. Use `-x` to avoid that. And why would you use `-f`? Why make the command more destructive than it needs to be? And what if `fileNames.txt` does't exist or isn't readable? You just deleted every single file in the directory with no warning (and this would include special files since you're using `-f`).

Comment: no idea why, but when I tried it didn't work for me - till I removed the "&> /dev/null" part (I did it as one liner with semicolons if that matters); Ubuntu WSL2

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a solution that works, but I thought I'd offer this one as well, as it might still be of help to you or someone else.

```
find /Path/To/TestDir -type f ! -name '.*' -exec basename {} + | grep -xvF -f /Path/To/filenames.txt"
```

#### Breakdown

**`find`:** This gets file paths in the specified directory (which would be `TestDir`) that match the given criteria.  In this case, I've specified it return only regular files (**`-type f`**) whose names don't start with a period (**`-name '.*'`**).  It then uses its own builtin utility to execute the next command:

**`basename`:**  Given a file path (which is what `find` spits out), it will return the base filename only, or, more specifically, everything after the last `/`.

**`|`:**  This is a command pipe, that takes the output of the previous command to use as input in the next command.

**`grep`:** This is a regular-expression matching utility that, in this case, is given two lists of files: one fed in through the pipe from `find`—the files of your `TestDir` directory; and the files listed in `filenames.txt`.  Ordinarily, the filenames in the text file would be used to match against filenames returned by `find`, and those that match would be given as the output.  However, the **`-v`** flag inverts the matching process, so that `grep` returns those filenames that **do not** match.

What results is a list of files that exist in the directory `TestDir`, but **do not** appear in the `filenames.txt` file.  These are the files you wish to delete, so you can simply use this line of code inside a parameter expansion **`$(...)`** to supply **`rm`** with the files it's able to delete.

The full command chain—after you `cd` into `TestDir`—looks like this:

```
rm $(find . -type f ! -name '.*' -exec basename {} + | grep -xvF -f filenames.txt")
```